# The execution of my if condition

Tags: javascript

I have this `javascript`condition:

```
if((modeAppelant == "ajout" && val < 2) || (modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0)){
    check = false;
    alert("Vous devez saisir au moins un contact");
}
```

For example, when i have:

- `val=2`
- `modeAppelant="ajout"`
- `numContacts=0`

I go in anyway in my `if` condition , why?

My `OR` not work ..?

Comment: because `modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0` is true?

Comment: Your second condition is `(modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0)` , so it's normal that go in with `numContacts=0`

Comment: Logical `OR`... If either of the condition is satisfied, second one is not tested at all....

Comment: @RayonDabre My `OR` not work ..?

Comment: _My OR not work_ ? What do you mean ?

Comment: where are u from? maybe someone can explain better in ur main language

Answer (score 1):

That's bexcuase you are using this condtion

```
(modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0)
```

Which is true from your data set

- `val=2`
- `modeAppelant="ajout"`
- `numContacts=0`

**OR** condition will check for a `true` value until it's find a one..On the contrary **AND** will continue until it's find a `false`. If It's found a false value,It Wouldn't go further.

Comment: Your **OR** is doing fine. In **OR** condition will check for a true condition at the end of the chain. @Mercer

Answer (score 1):

because of the second part of your conditional expression:

```
(modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0)
```

Comment: your Or works great :) that is why you are stepping into if block

Answer (score 1):

`false || true` will evaluate to `true`. In your case `(modeAppelant == "ajout" && val < 2)` is `false` but `(modeAppelant == "ajout" && numContacts <= 0)` is `true`. Therefore your if condition is executed.